# Self invoke function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Self invoke function call repeats but function code has problem repeating function output.

**Javascript**

```
//version 2
 ! function anf1(){
 if(w0 = '0') { //always true will be executed
    $('.fish1').stop().animate({'margin-left': w50, 'margin-top': '30px' }, 25000); //move object to the center of screen
    console.log('start');
}
if(w50 = w50) { //always true will be executed after 1st if condition
    $('.fish1').stop().animate({'margin-left': w70, 'margin-top': '-30px'}, 9000); //move object to 70% of browser width
    console.log('middle')
}
if(w70 = w70) { //always true will be executed after the 2nd if condition
    $('.fish1').stop().animate({'margin-left': ww, 'margin-top': '-45px'}, 35000, function(){
     anf1(); // call self invoked function anf1
     }); //move object to 100% of browser width
    console.log('finish')
}
}();
```

**HTML**

JSfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/qytkg5h2/2/

Comment: = is not == ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `==` for comparison `=` is used for assignment. Also set the original css in the end animate before calling the function again.

```
//window 100%
var ww = $('.container').outerWidth();
//window 0%
var w0 = ww - ww;
//window 50%
var w50 = ww / 2;
//window 70%
var w70 = (70 / 100) * ww;


//version 1
 ! function anf1(){
 if(w0 == '0') { //always true will be executed
    $('.fish1').stop().animate({'margin-left': w50, 'margin-top': '30px' }, 2500); //move object to the center of screen

    console.log('start');
}
if(w50 == w50) { //always true will be executed after 1st if condition
    $('.fish1').stop().animate({'margin-left': w70, 'margin-top': '-30px'}, 900); //move object to 70% of browser width
    console.log('middle')

}
if(w70 == w70) { //always true will be executed after the 2nd if condition
    $('.fish1').stop().animate({'margin-left': ww, 'margin-top': '-45px'}, 3500, function(){
     $(this).css({
  'margin-left': '0px',
  'margin-top': '0px'});
     anf1();
     // call self invoked function anf1
     }); //move object to 100% of browser width
    console.log('finish')

}
}();
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qytkg5h2/4/)**